# Using RedirectView.as_view in conjunction with i18n_patterns

Tags: python, django

i18n_patterns is working fine in my project, however, having `(r'^support/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/helpdesk/tickets/')),` in my urls.py redirects to the default language instead of the currently active one.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic url using `reverse`, `/helpdesk/tickets/` is a static urlpattern which should probably throw a `404` if the language setting is other than default, in this case, english.

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('', 
    (_(r'^helpdesk/tickets/$', HelpdeskView.as_view(), name='tickets')
    (_(r'^support/$'), RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('tickets'))
)
```

Comment: Be more specific, you don't get free tested code here at SO. I just gave you the idea behind dynamic redirection.